# NSDateFormatter is showing wrong date format (nachm. instead of PM) in the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

Why does the simulator is showing me `10:30 nachm.` instead of `10:30 PM`? I use the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"h:mm a"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateformat stringFromDate: myDate]);
```

OK I think I have to set a Locale somewhere ...

Comment: Don't hard code any am/pm scheme as it's not used in every country (`h` is for 1-12h representation..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the language in your simulator is set to German. Than nachm. means Nachmittags. And that's equal to PM. Take a look at the settings in the simulator. ;-)

Comment: General -> International -> Region Format -> United States (e.g.)

I thought setting the language is enough. But it seems it isn't. Thanks.

Comment: “10:30 nachmittags” is also absolutely uncommon since “nachmittags” normally is the time between noon and evening (10:30 P.M. is mostly __not__ “nachmittags”). I'm not sure if it exactly matches “afternoon” but it's an misleading translation of “P.M.”. Nevertheless in Germany the 24h representation is much more common.

Comment: There simply **isn't** a 1:1 translation for 10:30pm to German. You shouldn't be assuming and/or hard coding that kind of formatting as it's a locale setting on its own right..