# How do I tell if app has been opened without URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

I know I can check if a URL has been used to open my application, like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
          openURL:(NSURL*)url
sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation'
```

... but how do I check if the user has only returned to the app (and update my interface accordingly), without a URL being used? The use case is when logging in to Facebook or Twitter via Safari, and then user just goes back to the app instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`

Comment: Is an answer starting with "I think" really an answer?

Comment: To answer Sandros Question: [Exhibit 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945377/457406), [Ex. 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5080290/457406), [Ex. 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3726516/457406), [Ex. 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6889604/457406), [Ex. 5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5729092/457406), [Ex. 6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542121/457406). Obviously it is possible to start an answer with "I think". SCNR ;-)